# Python web scraping

Tags: python

On using this regular expression in python :

`pathstring = '<span class="titletext">(.*)</span>'`
`pathFinderTitle = re.compile(pathstring)`

My output is:

```
Govt has nothing to do with former CAG official RP Singh:
Sibal</span></a></h2></div><div class="esc-lead-article-source-wrapper">
<table class="al-attribution single-line-height" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody><tr><td class="al-attribution-cell source-cell">
<span class='al-attribution-source'>Times of India</span></td>
<td class="al-attribution-cell timestamp-cell">
<span class='dash-separator'>&nbsp;- </span>
<span class='al-attribution-timestamp'>&lrm;46 minutes ago&lrm;
```

The text find should have stopped at first "< /span>".

Please suggest whats wrong here.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 2):

`.*` is a *greedy* match of any characters; it is going to consume as many characters as possible. Instead, use the non-greedy version `.*?`, as in

```
pathstring = '<span class="titletext">(.*?)</span>'
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question instead of telling him to not use regular expressions

Comment: His question is titled "Python web scraping" - so there is an implicit question "How do I do web scraping?". Regular expressions are not the answer.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [pyquery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) instead of going mad on regular expressions... It's based on lxml and makes HTML parsing easy as using jQuery.

Something like this is everything you need:

```
doc = PyQuery(html)
doc('span.titletext').text()
```

You could also use [beautifulsoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.2.1), but the result is always the same: don't use regular expressions for parsing HTML, there are tools out there for making your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

`.*` will match `</span>` so it keeps on going until the last one.

The best answer is: Don't parse html with regular expressions.  Use the [lxml](http://lxml.de/installation.html) library (or something similar).

```
from lxml import html

html_string = '<blah>'
tree = html.fromstring(html_string)
titles = tree.xpath("//span[@class='titletext']")
for title in titles:
    print title.text
```

Using a proper xml/html parser will save you massive amounts of time and trouble.  If you roll your own parser, you'll have to cater for malformed tags, comments, and myriad other things.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just as easily use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is great for doing this kind of thing.

```
#using BeautifulSoup4, install by "pip install BeautifulSoup4"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
result = soup.find('span', 'titletext')
```

And then `result` would hold the `<span>` with class `titletext` as you're looking for.